# how to extract the digits from the center of a column of data in a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, numpy

I want to know how to extract the 3 digits from the center of the data from a column of a dataframe, which can change the number of digits.

To do this I used the function str[1:4], where '1' is the value of digits to the right and '4' is the value of digits to the left. However, the number of digits in the column to be evaluated can change, so I obtained the data of digits to the right and digits to the left by means of a mathematical calculation, and their number is in the columns called 'right' and ' left'.

I want such numbers to be able to be included in the 'str' statement like this: str[df['right']:df['left]]. However doing it this way results in null or 'NaN'.

I appreciate if you can advise me on how to resolve this question.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

seed = int(input("Write the seed = 3 digits")) #the seed must be 3 digits

digits = len(str(seed)) #The result will be 3 digits

meansq = pd.DataFrame()

meansq['ID'] = range(100)

meansq['xi'] = np.random.randint(0, 999, size=100)

meansq['xi2'] = pow(meansq['xi'],2)

meansq['length'] = meansq['xi2'].apply(lambda x : len(str(x)))

meansq['right'] = ((meansq['length']-digits)/2).astype(int)

meansq['left'] = (meansq['length']-meansq['right']).astype(int)

meansq['xi_2'] = meansq['xi2'].astype(str)

#meansq['center'] = meansq['xi_2'].str[means['right']:meansq['left']]

meansq['center'] = meansq['xi_2'].str[1:4]

meansq.head()
```

[image: meansq['center'] = meansq['xi_2'].str[1:4]]

[image: meansq['center'] = meansq['xi_2'].str[means['right']:meansq['left']]]

Answer (score 0):

```
meansq['center'] = [str(i)[1:4] for i in meansq['xi_2']]
```